# Writing / Reading binary file in Android Compose to shared storage

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I would like to save binary data to a file in my Android application, and load this file at a later point. The file should be accessible to the user - they should be able to transfer it to another device and load it there (think export/import data).

However, there have seemingly been many ways of interacting with storage over the years, and I am having real trouble understanding how to best accomplish this simple task today. I am using Jetpack Compose.

I found the following code in another question. This gets me as far as being able to create a (blank) file. However, I am unsure of how I should write to it, and how I should read it back later.

```
    val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
        pickedUri = it.data?.data
    }

    Button(
        onClick = {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT)
                .apply {
                    addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
                    type = "application/octet-stream"
                    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "export.dat")
                }
            launcher.launch(intent)
        }
    ) {
        Text("Select")
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the `Uri` to your viewmodel. Inside of a coroutine, your viewmodel can use `ContentResolver` and `openOutputStream()` to get an `OutputStream` on the location identified by the `Uri`. The viewmodel can then write to the `OutputStream` before flushing and closing it. Meanwhile, the viewmodel can emit a viewstate reflecting the current status (e.g., writing in progress, writing completed). Your composable can observe that viewstate to update a progress spinner or whatever to reflect in the UI the state of the write operation.

Most of this has little to do with Compose UI. You can read more about the `ContentResolver` portion in:

- [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#edit)
- [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/AndExplore/pages/chap-t29-001.html) of [this free book of mine](https://commonsware.com/AndExplore/)
- Lots of other posts, books, courses, etc.

And, [this blog post](https://www.composables.com/tutorials/activityresultcontract) demonstrates doing this work directly in a composable. I don't really recommend that, and I *definitely* do not recommend writing the content on the main application thread (instead of in a launched coroutine on a non-`Main` dispatcher).